# Python array changes values without reason

Tags: python, pycharm

In the following code, there is no reason I can see why variable "cleary" would change value, but it does. I have restarted pyCharm multiple times but it keeps happening.

```
import numpy as np

nPeriods = 48
nGens = 1
cleary = np.zeros((nPeriods,nGens,2))
clearz = np.zeros((nPeriods,nGens))

for ii in range(nPeriods):
    for jj in range(nGens):
        temp = cleary
        temp[ii,jj,:] = 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is expected behavior. Check out the documentation

Comment: Why do you expect that restarting your editor will change the core behavior of the Python language?

Comment: Duplicate: [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. Why is this and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior. You passed the reference of the ndarray object the name `cleary` is pointing to to `temp` when you did:

```
temp = cleary
```

You can avoid modifying `cleary` by assigning a copy of the array to `temp`:

```
temp = cleary.copy()
```

Read [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) to learn more about the underpinnings of name assignments in Python.